# using Provider to avoid rebuild all widget tree in flutter

Tags: flutter, state, provider, stateful, listen

as my understand, one of Provider benefits is to avoid rebuild the widget tree, by calling build function, but when i try it practically with this simple example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:providerexamplelast/counterWidget.dart';

void main() => runApp(ChangeNotifierProvider<Provider1>(
  create: (_) => Provider1(),
  child:   MaterialApp(
    home: Counter(),
  ),
));

int n =0;
class Counter extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("${n++}");
var counter = Provider.of<Provider1>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: ()=> counter.counter(),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text("1"),
            SizedBox(height: 5,),
            countText(),
            SizedBox(height: 5,),
            Text("3"),
            SizedBox(height: 5,),
            Text("4"),

          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Widget countText(){
  return Builder(
    builder: (context){
      var count = Provider.of<Provider1>(context);
      return Text("${count.c}");
    },
  );
}
```

by using this part :

```
print("${n++}");
```

i noticed that (build) function is recall whenever i press the button and call (counter) function from provider?

so the question here it is just (Stateless) widget, how it rebuild again? and then why i need to use Provider if it is not solve this problem?

Edit: I heard about this way:

```
var counter = Provider.of<Provider1>(context, listen: false);
```

so is it solve this problem? and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var counter = Provider.of<Provider1>(context, listen: false);
```

The `Provider` is one of state management mechanism which flutter have, under the hood, Provider keeps track of the changes which are done inside the widget. It doesn't matter to `Provider` whether it's a `Stateless` widget or `Stateful` widget, It's gonna rebuild widget if anything gets change.

`listen: false` tells the `Provider` not to rebuild widget even if data gets modified.

Comment: thank you for reply, but if it is tells it not to rebuild widget, then why it is work in my example, (countText()) is rebuild again even if i make listen : false?

Comment: have you add listen:false to both used provider reference like Provider.of<Provider1>(context, listen: false)

Comment: yes, i try it also, same thing, but actually the (build) function may not recall because i don't see the (n) variable increasing , but i am wondering , what is listen : false doe's ?

Comment: I already added in my answer what it does,  I am not sure but it is not retriggering build method again after adding that means no issues at your end.

Comment: when i change countText() function to StatelessWidget, and make listen : false, nothing happened, that mean build function doesn't recal, so thank you, i think i understood not

Comment: Rebuilding the widget tree and rebuilding a particular widget are not the same thing. `Provider` is used to avoid rebuilding the whole widget tree and instead rebuild from the widget tree particular widgets   that listen to the change  from the `Provider`.